# How can I change the value of the button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In class I am making a tic tac toe game and have been stuck for 2 days trying to make the x's and o's appear and the assignment is due tomorrow!
Here is the assignment sheet:

COMPSCI20: Tic Tac Toe Assignment

Create an HTML file as shown above. The HTML file should contain the following:

- a page title and link to a CSS file
- a header division (with an ID) that contains text
- a main division (with an ID) containing a 3x3 table of clickable buttons (with a class and each having IDs)
- a footer division (with an ID) containing text
  Title + Links  Main + Table 
  Header  Footer 

Create a CSS file to style the content as shown above. The CSS file should contain the following:

- in the header division, define the font, background color, text alignment, and padding
- in the main division, define the background color and padding
- the buttons should have a defined height, width, font, background color, and border
- in the footer division, define the font, background color, text alignment and padding

Create a JS file that contains two global variables: one to store the player turn (X or O) and one to store the winner.
The JS file should also contain the following functions:

- a `Start()` function that sets the player turn to start as X and the winner to null
- a `ChooseSquare()` function that places the appropriate letter on the button clicked, disables the button
  clicked, and switches to other player’s turn
- a `CheckWin()` function that checks each possible winning combination and displays a message in the
  footer if a player has won

here's what I have:

```js
var winner;
var current;

function Start() {
  current = "x";
}

function ChooseSquare() {
  if (document.getElementById("button1").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button2").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button2").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button2").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button3").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button3").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button3").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button4").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button4").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button4").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button5").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button5").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button5").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button6").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button6").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button6").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button7").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button7").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button7").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button8").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button8").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button8").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button9").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button9").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button9").disabled = true;
    current = "o";
  }


  if (document.getElementById("button1").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;
    current = "x"
    1;
  } else if (document.getElementById("button2").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button2").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button2").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button3").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button3").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button3").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button4").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button4").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button4").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button5").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button5").value = "x";
    document.getElementById("button5").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button6").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button6").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button6").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button7").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button7").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button7").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button8").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button8").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button8").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  } else if (document.getElementById("button9").onclick) {
    document.getElementById("button9").value = "o";
    document.getElementById("button9").disabled = true;
    current = "x";
  }
}

function CheckWin() {
  var one = document.getElementById("button1");
  var two = document.getElementById("button2");
  var three = document.getElementById("button3");
  var four = document.getElementById("button4");
  var five = document.getElementById("button5");
  var six = document.getElementById("button6");
  var seven = document.getElementById("button7");
  var eight = document.getElementById("button8");
  var nine = document.getElementById("button9");
  //x wins
  if (one == "x" && two == "x" && three == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (one == "x" && four == "x" && seven == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (one == "x" && five == "x" && nine == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (two == "x" && five == "x" && eight == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (three == "x" && six == "x" && nine == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (three == "x" && five == "x" && seven == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (four == "x" && five == "x" && six == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (seven == "x" && nine == "x" && eight == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  //o wins
  if (one == "o" && two == "o" && three == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (one == "o" && four == "o" && seven == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (one == "o" && five == "o" && nine == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (two == "o" && five == "o" && eight == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (three == "o" && six == "o" && nine == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (three == "o" && five == "o" && seven == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (four == "o" && five == "o" && six == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (seven == "o" && nine == "o" && eight == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
}

function reset() {
  one.value = " "
  one.disabled = false
  two.value = " "
  two.disabled = false
  two.value = " "
  three.disabled = false
  three.value = " "
  four.disabled = false
  four.value = " "
  five.disabled = false
  five.value = " "
  six.disabled = false
  six.value = " "
  seven.disabled = false
  seven.value = " "
  eight.disabled = false
  eight.value = " "
  nine.disabled = false
  nine.disabled = false
}
```

```css
#Header {
  background-color: Red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Acme, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
}

#Main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
}

#Footer {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Times New Roman", serif;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  font-family: Acme, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Tic Tac Toe </title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme|Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="Start()">

  <div id="Header">
    <h1> Tic Tac Toe </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="Main">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="button1"> <input class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
        <td id="button2"> <input class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
        <td id="button3"> <input class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="button4"> <input class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
        <td id="button5"> <input class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
        <td id="button6"> <input class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="button7"> <input class="button" type="button" onClick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
        <td id="button8"> <input class="button" type="button" onClick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
        <td id="button9"> <input class="button" type="button" onClick="ChooseSquare()"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onClick='reset()' value="reset">
  </div>
  <div id="Footer">
    <p id="foot"> Read to Play? Click on a square!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not using `.onclick` correctly. You need to set it equal to a function. See example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#Examples). Also `document.getElementById("button1")`  etc... will never equal "x" or "o", you need to get its value

Comment: You can use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2r4ydjac/) as a simple helper example. For something that uses better conventions, you can use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2r4ydjac/1/).

Answer (score 0):

`if (document.getElementById("button1").onclick)` is not how you test if they clicked on `button1`. That just tests whether the `onclick` property contains anything, which it does because it contains the value of the `onclick="ChooseSquare()"` attribute.

You can fix this by making the function take a parameter. You can pass `this` as an argument to the function, then it can use that to update the button the user clicked on.

In `CheckWin()` you need to get the values of the buttons. Also, the IDs need to be on the `<button>` elements, not the `<td>`s.

In `reset()` you were using variables `one`, `two`, etc. but these were local to `CheckWin`. I changed it to just loop over all the elements with `class="button"`.

```js
var winner;
var current;

function Start() {
  current = "x";
}

function ChooseSquare(button) {
  button.value = current;
  current = (current == "x") ? "o" : "x";
  button.disabled = true; // Prevent clicking button twice
  CheckWin();
}

function CheckWin() {
  var one = document.getElementById("button1").value;
  var two = document.getElementById("button2").value;
  var three = document.getElementById("button3").value;
  var four = document.getElementById("button4").value;
  var five = document.getElementById("button5").value;
  var six = document.getElementById("button6").value;
  var seven = document.getElementById("button7").value;
  var eight = document.getElementById("button8").value;
  var nine = document.getElementById("button9").value;
  //x wins
  if (one == "x" && two == "x" && three == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (one == "x" && four == "x" && seven == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (one == "x" && five == "x" && nine == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (two == "x" && five == "x" && eight == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (three == "x" && six == "x" && nine == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (three == "x" && five == "x" && seven == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (four == "x" && five == "x" && six == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  if (seven == "x" && nine == "x" && eight == "x") {
    window.alert("player1 has won")
  }
  //o wins
  if (one == "o" && two == "o" && three == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (one == "o" && four == "o" && seven == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (one == "o" && five == "o" && nine == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (two == "o" && five == "o" && eight == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (three == "o" && six == "o" && nine == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (three == "o" && five == "o" && seven == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (four == "o" && five == "o" && six == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
  if (seven == "o" && nine == "o" && eight == "o") {
    window.alert("player2 has won")
  }
}

function reset() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".button")).forEach(b => {
    b.value = " ";
    b.disabled = false;
  });
}
```

```css
#Header {
  background-color: Red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Acme, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
}

#Main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
}

#Footer {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Times New Roman", serif;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  font-family: Acme, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Tic Tac Toe </title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme|Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="Start()">

  <div id="Header">
    <h1> Tic Tac Toe </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="Main">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> <input id="button1" class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
        <td> <input id="button2" class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
        <td> <input id="button3" class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <input id="button4" class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
        <td> <input id="button5" class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
        <td> <input id="button6" class="button" type="button" onclick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <input id="button7" class="button" type="button" onClick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
        <td> <input id="button8" class="button" type="button" onClick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
        <td> <input id="button9" class="button" type="button" onClick="ChooseSquare(this)"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onClick='reset()' value="reset">
  </div>
  <div id="Footer">
    <p id="foot"> Read to Play? Click on a square!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't resist...

```js
const main    = document.querySelector('#Main')
  ,   All_bt  = document.querySelectorAll('#Main > button')
  ,   btReset = document.querySelector('#bt-reset')
  ;
var current = 0
  , players = [ { cod: 'x', case: [ ] } 
              , { cod: 'o', case: [ ] } 
              ]
    ;
main.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button') return;
  e.target.textContent = players[current].cod;
  e.target.disabled = true
  players[current].case.push( e.target.id.slice(-3))

// check win...
    let Win = false
      , Kaz = []
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
      {
      Kaz = players[current].case.filter(K=>Number(K.charAt(0))===i)
      if (Kaz.length===3) { Win=true; break }
      Kaz = players[current].case.filter(K=>Number(K.charAt(2))===i)
      if (Kaz.length===3) { Win=true; break }
      }
    if (!Win)
      {
      Kaz = players[current].case.filter(K=>K==='1-1' || K==='2-2' || K==='3-3')
      Win = (Kaz.length===3)
      }
    if (!Win)
      {
      Kaz = players[current].case.filter(K=>K==='1-3' || K==='2-2' || K==='3-1')
      Win = (Kaz.length===3)
      }
   // console.log(Win)

    if (Win)
      {
      All_bt.forEach(bt=>
        { 
        bt.disabled=true
        if ( Kaz.includes(  bt.id.slice(-3)  ))
          { bt.className='Win' }
        })
      }
  current = ++current %2
  }

btReset.onclick=_=>
  {
  current = 0
  players[0].case.length = 0
  players[1].case.length = 0
  All_bt.forEach(bt=>{ bt.disabled=false; bt.textContent = '\u00a0'; bt.className='' })
  }
```

```css
#Main {
  display: block;
  --bt-size : 50px;
  width:180px;
}
#Main > button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--bt-size);
  height: var(--bt-size);
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.Win {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
#bt-reset { margin: 1em;}
```

```html
<div id="Main">
  <button id="bt-1-1">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-1-2">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-1-3">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-2-1">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-2-2">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-2-3">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-3-1">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-3-2">&nbsp;</button>
  <button id="bt-3-3">&nbsp;</button>
</div>

<button id="bt-reset">reset</button>
```