# How to check if the tiles are already filled with values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I have this problem solving how to see when tie happens, when the *X* wins and when the *O* wins.
Here's the code to determine the value of my tiles.

**Javascript code**

```js
let winner;
let winner2;

function checkValueForX() {
  if (
    board[0].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[1].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[2].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[3].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[4].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[5].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[6].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[7].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[8].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[0].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[4].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[8].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[2].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[4].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[6].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[0].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[3].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[6].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[2].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[5].textContent === 'X' &&
    board[8].textContent === 'X'
  ) {
    let winner = 'X';
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function checkValueForO() {
  if (
    board[0].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[1].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[2].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[3].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[4].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[5].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[6].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[7].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[8].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[0].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[4].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[8].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[2].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[4].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[6].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[0].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[3].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[6].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else if (
    board[2].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[5].textContent === 'O' &&
    board[8].textContent === 'O'
  ) {
    let winner2 = 'O';
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's my function to check if a player win or if a tie happens:

```js
function checkWinOrTie() {
  if (winner === true) {
    displayWinnwer.innerHTML = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer1 + '!';
  } else if (winner2 === true) {
    displayWinnwer.innerHTML = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer2 + '!';
  }
}
```

I know that there's still something missing here, can you help me to declare how to detect if there's a winner or tie?

PS. Newbie in JavaScript here pardon me.

Comment: Have you looked at examples like this one? https://www.thatsoftwaredude.com/content/6189/coding-tic-tac-toe-in-javascript

Comment: Yes but it seems they have a  different approach and problem.

Comment: What's not working about your existing code? You're checking combos-- albeit not as elegantly as other examples I see online-- so I'm not clear on what's missing from yours.  You say "I know that there's still [code] missing here."  Okay, then tell us what's missing.  Tell us very specifically which part you need help with.

Comment: I am missing the if statement that compares  if there's a winner already or none. I'm thinking to put that statement after ```else if(winner2 === true){
      displayWinnwer.innerHTML = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer2 + '!';
    }```

Comment: What should I write when I want to compare the result? If there's a winner or it's a tie. Yeah I can determine on my code who wins but when checking tie that's where I am lost right now.

Comment: If there's no winner and all boxes are filled, then you have a tie, right?  You're already checking if there's a winner, so you know that part.  Can't you just check if all boxes have been filled?  Do your "winner" checks first, and then `else if (all_boxes_filled) { declareTie(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two winners, right?

You can rewrite your `checkWinOrTie()` function like this:

```
function checkWinOrTie(){
    if (checkValueForX()){
      /* are you aware that you misspelled "displayWinnwer"? */
      displayWinnwer.innerHTML = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer1 + '!';
    } else if(checkValueForO()){
      displayWinnwer.innerHTML = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer2 + '!';
    } else if (isTie()) {
      displayWinnwer.innerHTML = 'There was a tie!';
    }
}
```

Run `checkWinOrTie()` each time a player completes a move.

And then write the `isTie()` function like this:

```
function isTie() {
   for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

      //this "if" check assumes your textContent would be "falsy" for boxes that haven't been filled yet
      if (!board[i].textContent) {
          return false; //because we found at least one empty box
      }
   }

   //at this point, code iterated over every box and did
   //not find a single empty box, so the board must be full
   return true;
}
```

Your code could be improved in a lot of ways.  But since you're asking specifically how to solve the problem with the approach you already established, this should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, i tried this on my codes but there's a problem. Why is the true returning whenever I click the board[0]? (first tile). I just  added else on the previous code.
```
 function isTie() {
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

       if (!board[i].textContent) {
        
           return false; 
       } else {
    
           return true;
       }
       
       
    }
 }
```

Comment: Because `return true;` should be outside of your `for` loop.  I.e., if you get through the whole loop without having returned `false`, then you know the board is full.  Essentially `isTie()` is just checking whether the board is full.  You may wish to rename it more appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I have already done something similar ...
find! : [How can I change the value of the button when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419043/how-can-i-change-the-value-of-the-button-when-clicked/59419845#59419845)

well, the approach is different, so here it is:

```js
const board =
  [ '-','-','-'  // 0 1 2
  , '-','-','-'  // 3 4 5
  , '-','-','-'  // 6 7 8
  ]
  
function check_LCD(pCod) {
  // check for Lines
  for(l=0;l<9; l+=3) 
    { if (board[l]===pCod && board[l+1]===pCod && board[l+2]===pCod) return true }

  // check for  Columns 
  for(c=0;l<4; c++)
    { if (board[c]===pCod && board[c+3]===pCod && board[c+6]===pCod) return true }

  // check for Diagonals
  return ( (board[0]===pCod && board[4]===pCod && board[8]===pCod)
        || (board[2]===pCod && board[4]===pCod && board[6]===pCod) )
  }

function checkWinOrTie()
  {
  winner_X = check_LCD('X')  
  winner_O = check_LCD('O')  

  if (winner_X) {
    displayWinnwer.textContent = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer1 + '!';
  }
  else if(winner_O) {
    displayWinnwer.textContent = 'Winner is ' + activePlayer2 + '!';
  }
}
```

using an array is less practical.

Comment: What am I missing?  This is using an array: `board `...  I upvoted your answer (too).